# React.Children.toArray... to ReactElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I filter items, I can access to the ReactElement properties, but when I want to sort the results, this properties are not existant. Why ? How to cast a ReactChild / Fragment / Portal to a ReactElement ?

```
const items:(React.ReactChild | 
    React.ReactFragment | 
    React.ReactPortal)[] = React.Children.toArray(props.children);

return items
    .filter((item:React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal) => {
        return (React.isValidElement(item) && item.type == Event) ?? item
    })
    .sort((item1, item2) => {
        return item1. <-- no type, no props
    })
);
```

Why I want to sort my items...

```
<myComponent>
   <myItem date="01/01/2022" title="Title A" />
   <myItem date="02/01/2022" title="Title B" />
   <myItem date="01/01/2022" title="Title C" />
</myComponent>
```

The result I want to render :

```
<h1>01/01/2022</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Title A</li>
    <li>Title C</li>
</ul>

<h1>02/01/2022</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Title B</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this at all? Sort the data that you're using to _generate_ those children, don't reach into the component and sort the rendered children. You should have zero reason to mess with the component internals: they're simply a consequence of what you do with the data that is used to construct the virtual DOM. If you sort your data and trigger a rerender the normal way, React will reorder (not rerender) all those elements accordingly. Provided you used proper `key` attributes.

Comment: Because I want to sort Items by date and wrap them into another components to display one date for a group of items.

Comment: Yes, so sort your _state data_ and then have React do what it's supposed to, and if you need a subset wrapped by another component, update its props with the subset you need it to wrap. Use React, don't use "the internal data layout that this version of React happens to be using under the hood".

Comment: No, I don't want to sort the state. I have edited my question.

Comment: Sounds like you want to group your data by date, then render it using headings and lists. As @Mike was saying, do that with the data and the component, not by altering the internals of React itself.

Comment: Why do you want to alter the internal of React... ??? I just want use React.Chidren to enumerate the children, sort them and add missing HTML structure. Do you have really understand my request ? The React.ReactChild, React.ReactFragment, React.ReactPortal are the type returned by the toArray method...

Comment: Yes: don't do that: that's using the React internals. Instead, sort the data that you're passing into the component that will render each group. And if you don't have components that represent a single group: the React methodology would be to _make one_ and then pass in the props they need (e.g. `heading` and `items` or something) and then have _that component_ do what it needs to do (e.g. have it rebind props.items in the component state, and sort the items according to a `props.sort` so that it renders what it should render).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's I ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way :

My Event component :

```
import React from "react";

import './styles.scss';

export interface IEvent {
    title: string;
    date: Date;
    description: string;
}

const Event = (props:IEvent):JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <li><h2>{props.title}</h2>{props.description}</li>
    );
}

export default Event;
```

My Events component :

```
type EventType = ReactElement<IEvent, any>;

interface IEventsSorted {
   date: Date,
   events: Array<EventType>,
}

interface IEvents {
   children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
} 

const Events = (props:IEvents):JSX.Element => {

    const getEvents = (): JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] => {

        let previousDate: Date | null = null;

        const items = React.Children
            // Only to access to map methods
            .map(props.children, c => c)
            // Filer children to Event component
            .filter((item: EventType) => {
                return item.type == Event ?? item
            })
            // Sort Events by date
            .sort((item1: EventType, item2: EventType) => {
                return +(item1.props.date.getTime() - item2.props.date.getTime() );
            })
            // Group Events by date
            .reduce((previousValue: Array<IEventsSorted>, currentValue: EventType, index: number) => {
                let eventsSorted: Array<IEventsSorted> = previousValue;

                if (previousDate?.getTime() !== currentValue.props.date.getTime()) {
                    previousDate = currentValue.props.date;

                    eventsSorted.push({
                        date: currentValue.props.date,
                        events: [currentValue]
                    });
                } else {
                    eventsSorted.filter(e => e.date.getTime() == currentValue.props.date.getTime())[0]
                      .events.push(currentValue);
                }

                return eventsSorted;
            }, [])
            // Display groupes and items
            .map((eventsSorted:IEventsSorted, index: number) => {
                return <div key={index}> 
                            <span className={index==0 ? "first" : ""}>   {eventsSorted.date.toLocaleString("fr-FR",{day: 'numeric',month: 'long'})}</span>
                            <ul>{eventsSorted.events}</ul>
                        </div>
            });

        return items;
     }

    return (
        <div className="events">{ getEvents() }</div>
    );
 }

 export default Events;
```

How I use it :

```
            <Events>
                <Event title="Title 1" date={new Date(2022, 8, 25)} description="Desc 1" />
                <Event title="Title 2" date={new Date(2022, 0, 29)} description="Desc 2" />
                <Event title="Title 3" date={new Date(2022, 0, 29)} description="Desc 3" />
                <Event title="Title 4" date={new Date(2022, 6, 21)} description="Desc 4" />
            </Events>
```

The result :

[image]